# HTML img src appending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a loop in php that creats a button and when that button is clicked a modal opens and certain data is passed to it.

```
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) :?>
<button type="button" class="open-details-modal btn btn-primary"
      data-id-number="<?php echo $product['ProductID'];?>
      "data-id-image="<?php echo $product['Image'];?>"
      "data-id-image-two="<?php echo $product['Image2'];?>"
      "data-id-image-three="<?php echo $product['Image3'];?>"
```

I have a script that helps translate the data

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open-details-modal").click(function() {
      $("#name").text($(this).attr('data-id-product-name'));
      $("#image").text($(this).attr('data-id-image'));
      $("#image2").text($(this).attr('data-id-image-two'));
      $("#image3").text($(this).attr('data-id-image-three'));
```

Lets say the value of

```
"data-id-image" = ABCDEF
```

I am not sure if i need to convert this into a javascript variable or a php variable.

What i want to do is be able to say

```
<img src = "(#php or javascript variable)" +"001.jpg">
```

How can i achieve this in either php or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that #image is your image, something like this:

```
  $(".open-details-modal").click(function() {
      $("#name").text($(this).attr('data-id-product-name'));
      $("#image").text($(this).attr('data-id-image'));
      $("#image").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-id-image") + "001.jpg");
  }
```

Comment: so how will i call $("#image").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-id-image") + "001.jpg"); when i need to use it in html?

Comment: Is there just one image for the modal or are there many? - I assumed there was one and it gets updated when you click one of the buttons.  Might need to see some more of your html.

Comment: I have edited my code. There will be multiple <img src> tags in my html. each one will get the data for different images.